What is the nature of spin-$j$ representations of $SU(2)$ group used in QM? Elements of $SU(2j+1)$?

The $j=1$ representation of $J_x,J_y$ and $J_z$ is QM, are all hermitian, and traceless matrices. Therefore, the corresponding rotation matrices, $$U(\hat{n},\alpha)=e^{-iJ_k\alpha_k/\hbar},$$ are $3\times 3$ unitary matrices, having determinant equal to one. Therefore, the $j=1$ representations of $SU(2)$ are matrices are a subset of ${\rm SU}(3)$. I am almost sure that this is true.

Next, the $j=3/2$ representation of $J_x,J_y,J_z$ in QM are:
$$
J_x = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 \\
0 & \sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
, \quad 
J_y = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -i\sqrt{3} & 0 \\
0 & i\sqrt{3} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
\quad
J_z = \frac{\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -3
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which are again all hermitian and traceless. Therefore, the corresponding rotation matrices, $$U(\hat{n},\alpha)=e^{-iJ_k\alpha_k/\hbar},$$ are $4\times 4$ unitary matrices with determinant one. Therefore, the $j=3/2$ representations of $SU(2)$ are matrices which are a subset of ${\rm SU}(4)$.



Therefore, I am tempted to conclude that the spin-$j$ unitary representations of $SU(2)$ are matrices which are a subset of ${\rm SU}(2j+1)$? Have I got this right?

They’re also a subgroup of $GL(2j+1)$. But why is being a subgroup relevant?

@Ghoster If spin-j representation constitutes a subgroup of $SU(2j+1)$, it is trivially a subgroup of $GL(2j+1)$. What's the point? All I wanted to know was whether my understanding was on the right track.

My point is that I don’t think it matters the slightest in physics that the spin-3/2 irrep of SU(2) is a subgroup of SU(4) or GL(4) or anything else. All that matters is that it’s a 4-dimensional representation of SU(2).

This is correct.  What matters is the way the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is embedded inside each set of unitary matrices.  The way you have set it up is by an irreducible embedding so there is no $n$-dimensional subspace left invariant under the action of your $\mathfrak{su}(2)$.
You could of course consider $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ as a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{su}(n)$ and embed it differently.  For instance, construct $3\times 3$ hermitian matrices and consider the subset of $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ matrices given by the Pauli’s placed in the upper left corner.  In this case, your $3\times 3$ matrices break up into a 2-dimensional subspace $\oplus$ a 1-dimensional subspace.
Because in physics we are (for the very large part) interested in unitary representations, pretty much everything is eventually a subset of the $n\times n$ unitaries.  The distinction with $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ is that the machinery of representation theory guarantees there are always $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ floating around in any dimension, but there may not be - say - irreducible representation of $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ of dimension $11$, and the only way to get an 11-dimensional representation of $\mathfrak{so}(5)$ is if this representation is reducible.

Thanks for the detailed answer. One clarification. I said that the spin-$j$ unitary irrep of SU(2) is a subset of $SU(2j+1)$. It must also be a subgroup. Does that subgroup have a standard name/notation?
